# SpringBeanAutowiringSupport vs WebApplicationContextUtils

Tags: spring, jax-ws, autowired

This is in context to a web application. My Impl class has `JAX-WS` annotations and `@Autowired` annotation is not working.
I get null pointer exception while retrieving the Autowired objects.

Found to solutions, both work:

1. Extend `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` and keep `@Autowired` annotations intact.
2. Use `WebApplicationContextUtils` to get the `WebapplicationContext` where beans are loaded. getBean() from this context given me the required bean.

Now, the documentation of `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` class says in NOTE 
"**If there is an explicit way to access the ServletContext, prefer such a way over using this class. The WebApplicationContextUtils class allows for easy access to the Spring root web application context based on the ServletContext.**"

What does this mean? In my web application, I am not using any servlets. My web application is also not an ONLY `JAX-WS` application. It is a web application with `SOAP/REST webservices` and `EJBs` as well.

Which method to prefer and why? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Extending SpringBeanAutoWiringSupport is mentioned as the preffered way in the spring docs. Isn't this method also better since you wouldn't have to explicitly access the beans from the webcontext?

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-web-services

Comment: Thanks John. It definitely looks better and easier to implement. But, I want to understand the intent of the NOTE mentioned in the docs here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html

Answer (score 0):

One nice example of use is when you have a web service and you wish to autowire many other spring beans that you made. This looks more elegant than using Context Utils.

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://yada/yada", endpointInterface = "com.ISomeWS", serviceName = "SomeWS") 
public class SomeWS extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements ISomeWS {
    @Autowired ISpringService springService;
    public WSImportResponse processXMLContent(SomeType xmlContent) throws Exception {
        springService.say("Hello");
    }
}
```